# Why is the compatible build agent not building?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I recently upgraded my deployment build configuration to use Powershell V3.0 (from 2.0).  I installed the necessary [Microsoft package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) on my agent and the agent `$PSVersionTable` shows `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}` locally.

After manually queuing the build, the queue displays:

[image: Teamcity build queue showing now compatible agents]

However, when clicking 'More details >>', my agent is listed as compatible:

[image]

**Why is the compatible build agent not building?**

I've also followed the instructions to refresh the build agent by deleting some of the folders as indicated in [this post](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/311239).

Teamcity 8.0.2

**Update**

Installing Powershell v3.0 on the incompatible agent allows the system to build the configuration just fine, however, forcibly choosing my agent still won't build.

Comment: Why does the "unmet requirements" list "powershell_x86 matches **3\.0**" with a backslash? I tried doing the same config locally and it doesn't show the backslash...

Comment: I assume it's just escaping the `.` ? Not sure...it's a default setting on my system.

Comment: I wonder whether this issue is what you're experiencing. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-31311

Comment: @PaulHunt, it could be related but the only dependency sharing I have is an Artifact Dependency using the built-in options.

Comment: Updating TeamCity could be worth a try, there was a bug I reported about TeamCity incorrectly marking agents as not compatible which got fixed in 8.0.7 EAP: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-32528